# What is the underlying reason for not being able to put arrays of pointers in unsafe structs in C#?

Tags: c#, pointers, d, unsafe, struct

If one could put an array of pointers to child structs inside unsafe structs in C# like one could in C, constructing complex data structures without the overhead of having one object per node would be a lot easier and less of a time sink, as well as syntactically cleaner and much more readable.

Is there a deep architectural reason why fixed arrays inside unsafe structs are only allowed to be composed of "value types" and not pointers?

I assume only having explicitly named pointers inside structs must be a deliberate decision to weaken the language, but I can't find any documentation about why this is so, or the reasoning for not allowing pointer arrays inside structs, since I would assume the garbage collector shouldn't care what is going on in structs marked as unsafe.

Digital Mars' D handles structs and pointers elegantly in comparison, and I'm missing not being able to rapidly develop succinct data structures; by making references abstract in C# a lot of power seems to have been removed from the language, even though pointers are still there at least in a marketing sense.

Maybe I'm wrong to expect languages to become more powerful at representing complex data structures efficiently over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just guessing, but it might have to do with different pointer sizes for different target platforms. It seems that the C# compiler is using the size of the elements directly for index calculations (i.e. there is no CLR support for calculating fixed sized buffers indices...)

Anyway you can use an array of `ulong`s and cast the pointers to it:

```
unsafe struct s1
{
  public int a;
  public int b;
}

unsafe struct s
{
  public fixed ulong otherStruct[100];
}

unsafe void f() {
  var S = new s();
  var S1 = new s1();
  S.otherStruct[4] = (ulong)&S1;
  var S2 = (s1*)S.otherStruct[4];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

One very simple reason: dotNET has a **compacting** garbage collector. It moves things around. So even if you could create arrays like that, you would have to *pin* every allocated block and you would see the system slow down to a crawl.

But you are trying to optimize based on an assumption. Allocation and cleanup of objects in dotNET is highly optimized. So write a working program first and then use a profiler to find your bottlenecks. It will most likely not be the allocation of your objects.

Edit, to answer the latter part:

> Maybe I'm wrong to expect languages to
>   become more powerful at representing
>   complex data structures efficiently
>   over time.

I think C# (or any managed language) is much more powerful at representing
complex data structures (efficiently). By changing from low level pointers to garbage collected references.

Comment: That cannot be the reason, since you can very well use pointers to other unsafe structures inside unsafe structures (there's no problem with creating a binary tree structure that way ...) The restriction applies only to arrays inside unsafe structs (so called fixed size buffers), and the reason for this is not obvious in my opinion (See my response for a possible explanation)

Answer (score 1):

Putting a fixed array of pointers in a struct would quickly make it a bad candidate for a struct. The recommended size limit for a struct is 16 bytes, so on a x64 system you would be able to fit only two pointers in the array, which is pretty pointless.

You should use classes for complex data structures, if you use structures they become very limited in their usage. You wouldn't for example be able to create a data structure in a method and return it, as it would then contain pointers to structs that no longer exists as they were allocated in the stack frame of the method.

Comment: Interesting. Can you give a link to some articles, or explain a little why 16 bytes?

Comment: @Alexander: It's what Microsoft says in their guidelines: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y23b5415%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: The size threshold where a class will become more efficient than a struct varies considerably with usage patterns.  Immutable classes smaller than 16 bytes will very seldom be more efficient than structures outside contrived scenarios, but with many usage patterns even "big" (64-256 bytes) structures may outperform classes.  For some usage patterns, the "winning margin" for structures actually increases with bigger payloads (provided they're not so big as to crash the stack).

Comment: @supercat: The threshold for the size when a structure becomes inefficient is based on how structures of different sizes work. The performance of structs and classes aren't really comparable, because their use is so different. A complex data structure should simply not be a struct at all.

Comment: @Guffa: A 25-byte structure will often perform more than 5% slower than a 24-byte structure [that threshold used to be 16 bytes], but the time to construct a structure of practically *any* size and return it to a method which will copy the data out of it and then abandon it will be far less than the time to construct an immutable class object holding the same data.  Class references are cheaper to copy, but that's only a benefit if they actually *are* copied before they're abandoned.  If they're not, the extra time to create a class object is simply wasted.

Comment: @supercat: You are missing the point. The threshold is a guideline to decide if a struct should be or not, it's not for choosing between using a struct and a class. That should be done on completely different criteria.

Comment: @Guffa: Your answer starts out by saying that an array holding more than four pointers would be a bad candidate for a struct because of its size.  I agree with your comment that a struct-vs-class decision should be largely based upon factors other than size.  As for the relative safety of returning a a structure that contains pointer-type members, I don't see why a struct containing a fixed array of pointers would be any more dangerous than any other means of returning pointers.

Comment: @supercat: No, returning pointers would be equally bad in any form.